# Method's return doesn't display [React Native]

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have an issue with a method in my code (React Native).

I have an array of IDs and I would like to make a 'GET' request in each ID to display a preview card for each.

That's why I used the 'map' method on my array.
The request works fine and then I call my method `cardUser(user)` to display.

That's the part of my code where I do the map (Works fine):

```
render() {
    if (!this.state.isLoaded) {
        return (
            <Spinner color='#84568c' />
        );
    } else {
        var user = this.state.user;
        return (
            <ScrollView
                refreshControl={
                    <RefreshControl
                        tintColor='#84568c'
                        refreshing={this.state.refreshing}
                        onRefresh={this._onRefresh.bind(this)} />
                }
            >
                <Content padder>
                     {user.following.map(following => (
                        this.getUserByID(following)
                     ))}
                </Content>
            </ScrollView>
        );
    }
}
```

I call `getUserByID()` (Works fine):

```
getUserByID(id) {
    fetch(api.base_url + api.user_url + '/' + id, {
        method: "GET",
        headers: { 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + this.state.token }
    })
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((responseData) => {
        this.cardUser(responseData);
    })
    .done();
}
```

Now that I have my response in `responseData` I want to diplay and lay out each `user`. So I call `cardUser()` with an `user` object each time.

```
cardUser(user) {
    console.log(user.id);
    return (
        <TouchableHighlight underlayColor='transparent' key={user.id}
            onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('UserProfile', {id: user.id})} onLongPress={() => this.alertUserId(user.id)} >
            <View style={container.card}>
                    <View style={container.cardUser}>
                        <Image source={{uri: user.banner}} style={{position: 'absolute', width: '100%', height: 170, borderRadius: 20}} />
                        <View style={container.darkLayer}>
                            <Left>
                                <Thumbnail large source={{uri: user.photo}} style={{alignSelf: 'center'}}/>
                            </Left>
                            <Body>
                                <View style={{alignItems: 'center'}}>
                                    <Text style={text.pseudoHomepage}>{user.username}</Text>
                                    <Text style={[text.stats, {color: 'white'}]}>{user.first_name}</Text>
                                </View>
                            </Body>
                            <Right>
                                <Icon ios='ios-medal' android='md-medal' style={{color: 'white', alignSelf: 'center', fontSize: 40}}/>
                            </Right>
                        </View>
                        <View style={container.darkFooterLayer}>
                            <Text numberOfLines={2} style={text.bioFotter}>{user.bio}</Text>
                        </View>
                    </View>
            </View>
        </TouchableHighlight>
    );
}
```

But that's not display anything... However if I make a `console.log(user)` it shows the right things in my logs ! In the right order and no duplicated object or anything else...

Moreover if I put a `console.log(user)` in the `return()` it shows the right thing too and I don't have any error or warning message.

I hope I was clear enough, if you need additional informations tell me.
Have a nice day thank you !

(Sorry if I misspelt, English is not my language)

Comment: if you take out the transparent underlay color does it show?

Comment: try replacing the transparent underlayColor with a low active opacity (but not 0 opacity) and see if it shows up then..

Comment: No because that worked with an other configuration before but I change my API so I had to make like this.

Comment: I also tried to juste put a <Text>TEST<Text/> and it not showing anything

Comment: where is the actual render component? I see a lot of functions being called but no render?

Comment: the 'map' is in the render() method, many thing are diplay like the header or a tabNavigator but not the content called in the map

Comment: can't see your full code. You may need to create more than one component and then import components into the map code

Comment: I update the post, then you can see the render method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you need to fetch all the data. You can't do it in the render method.

```
componentDidMount() {
  Promise.all(this.state.user.following.map(this.fetchUser))
    .then(userFetchedArray => this.setState({ usersList: userFetchedArray }))
}

fetchUser(id) {
  return fetch(api.base_url + api.user_url + '/' + id, {
    method: "GET",
    headers: { 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + this.state.token }
  })
  .then((response) => response.json());
}
```

Then you need to render fetched data:

```
render() {
...
<Content padder>
  {this.state.usersList.map(this.cardUser)}
</Content>
...
```

Callback passed to map should return jsx, but in your case, it returns `undefined` (getUserByID function return nothing). Also this callback can't be an async

Comment: thanks but with your response I have this warning :

[Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: _this4.cardUser is not a function. (In '_this4.cardUser(responseData)', '_this4.cardUser' is undefined)]

Do you know why ?

Comment: have you bound the component to methods?